# Initializing custom properties in entity sub class

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to initialize an array to an entity sub class of NSManagedObject not NSObject class.

When I try to initialize the array I get an error

> unrecognized selector sent to instance.

I am trying to initialize the array like this

```
Entity.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

How can I stop the error?

Comment: it seems you're trying to access the property on the class (+) rather than on the instance (-)

Comment: The property is declared in the header as @property (nonatomic, strong). It should be public?

Comment: How `Entity` declared and initialized?

Comment: myArray = [[self managedObjectContext]executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];